# VS2010 Productivity power tools and messed up menus

Tags: visual-studio-2010, productivity

In VS2010 I have the Productivity Power tools installed.  Mostly they are great. However, recently, my menus are all appearing in the uppermost left corner of the screen, and my files appear blank!

Has anyone else experienced this phenomenon?  There is too much noise to signal on the MS sites to find answers.

I can fix this by uninstalling the tools.  But I do really like them, just wish they did not screw things up.

[image: tools menu appearing in the upper left corner]

Comment: And upon reinstallation, the problem is not fixed?

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall fixes things, but only for a day or so.

Comment: Its there a way to reset productivity power tools to default settings? And if you disable PPT does the error go away?

Comment: The only option appears to be uninstall, no disable.  I uninstalled and reinstalled this morning.  After now about 5 hours of coding, it happened again.

Comment: Did you check in the add ons manger?

Comment: it does not show up under Add-In Manager, only under Extension Manager.  Aha, there I see it now, Disable.  I'll see if that helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Productivity tools sort file tabs alphabetically seemed to cause the problem for me, and when I turn this option off my menu is fine again!!  Weird!

This can be toggle from Tools | Options | Productivity Power Tools | Document Tab Well | General | Tab Sorting | Alphabetically